# HTML Body CSS Transform Scaling Up causing content to be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I am using CSS transform to scale up the whole body of a page. After scaling up a bit, content from corners start becoming un-viewable because they are outside visible ranges. Is there a way for the content to still be viewable by scrolling vertically or horizontally using transform scaling?

I am currently using Javascript to scale up the body like so

```
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(1.5)';
```

However, this cuts off some content from pages. I need it to work as I continue scaling up from 1.0.

Comment: can you brief a little as in why you even need to scale up the whole body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the transform-origin:

```
document.body.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleFactor + ')';
```

You may also need to adjust the width and height of the body to match the scaling.

```
var scaleFactor = 1.5;
document.body.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleFactor + ')';
document.body.style.width = 100 * scaleFactor + "%";
document.body.style.height = 100 * scaleFactor + "%";
```

A note concerning transforms. Transforms are imaginary and don't alter physical dimensions including x, y, width and height. So you'll have to manage these physical dimensions manually to match your "transform'd" dimensions in order to keep the scroll bars happy.

Comment: Thanks for the transformOrigin advice. This makes it better. The width and height changing distorts the page though, unfortunately